# How to set the Localization on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement to show a dynamic string which is retrieved from database to show in two languages (Sinhala and English).

Name in English: Chamara /
Name in Sinhala: චාමර

Is it possible to show the same text in different laguages in the same view?

if not how to set the culture of a specific view?

I tried the following to set the culture of a specific view but couldn't get it to work.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cultureString = "si-LK";    // i.e., en-us
            var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureString);//CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureString);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template";

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Is your problem setting the culture or displaying different views based on culture?

Comment: @svanelten setting the culture.

Comment: If you set the culture in a controller action you have to reset it for each request. More info: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) A better way for setting it might be a FilterAttribute.